# destructing ev.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

When I attempt to use Object destructuring with `ev.preventDefault()`, I receive the following error in Chrome:

`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

However, when I use `ev.preventDefault()` without destructuring, it works fine. Code that reproduces this issue is shown below.

```js
const button = document.getElementById(`test-button`);

button.onclick = ({ preventDefault }) => {
  preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<button id=test-button type=button>Click me to see the error</button>
```

Any idea why this is happening? Or how I can use Object destructuring with the Event Object?

Comment: You don't need the Event Object when destructuring?

Comment: Well, it's a method like any other, it must be called on the appropriate target (the event object) to know which default to prevent.

Comment: @zer00ne, @Bergi The `({ preventDefault })` in the function parameters is the Event Object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter for more examples of destructuring function parameters.

Comment: @dwhieb Yes. And when you do `preventDefault()`, that's not [method call syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and the event object is nowhere to be found: *Illegal invocation*.

Comment: @Bergi Interesting - I didn't realize destructuring doesn't bind its context. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`preventDefault` is a method that must be invoked on an event object to know which default to prevent. When you do just `preventDefault()`, that's not method call syntax and the event object is nowhere to be found: *Illegal invocation*. Destructuring syntax just accesses the value, it does not automatically bind any functions.

```
button.onclick = (e) => {
  const { preventDefault } = e; // like const preventDefault = e.preventDefault;
  preventDefault(); // does not work, unlike preventDefalt.call(e)
};
```